# How do I fix an express route with Stripe webhook that receives 404 and cannot GET

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments, express-router

I have a Vue app on the frontend and a seperate express server with only a few routes. In app.js, I registered my routes as follows:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
require('dotenv').config()
const orders = require('./routes/orders')
const webhooks = require('./routes/webhooks')
const app = express()

// http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))


// Register api routes
app.use('/', orders)
app.use('/create-payment-intent', orders)
app.use('/admin', orders)
app.use('/admin/:id', orders)
app.use('/webhook', webhooks)
/*
TODO - fall through route handler
*/
```

In /routes/orders.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const { flattenObject, orderValidationRules, validate } = 
require('../middlewares/validations')
const OrdersController = require('../controllers/ordersController')


router.route('/').post(
  orderValidationRules(),
  validate,
  OrdersController.apiPostOrder
  )
router.route('/admin').get(OrdersController.apiGetOrders)
router.route('/create-payment-intent').post(OrdersController.apiCreatePaymentIntent)
router.route('/:id').delete(OrdersController.apiDeleteOrder)

module.exports = router
```

/routes/webhooks

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const WebhooksController = require('../controllers/webhooksController')

router.route('/webhook').post(express.raw({type: 'application/json'}), 
WebhooksController.apiPostWebhookEvent)

module.exports = router
```

On the frontend, I can post my orders, hit admin route, the create-payment-intent route on the server is reached and responds 200, yet when I see if the webhook was reached on the stripe dashboard says pending and on the server 404 not found:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is an express routing issue and I am uncertain if I in fact set my routes properly. How do I fix this? Also on the localhost port for the server I get cannot get for /create-payment-intent and for /webhook, /admin is fine.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoojq.png

Comment: Have you added the remote url of your webhook in the stripe dashboard?

Comment: yes, I was tunneling using ngrok.

Comment: Can you update your answer with the code inside `WebhooksController.apiPostWebhookEvent` and also provide the output of `curl -v -X POST https://YOUR_URL_HERE/webhook`?